# ¿Como establecer Pagina de Login como Home Page en Django?

Tags: python, django, login

Actualmente cuando ejecuto la página, la dirección por default que me dirige es: `http://xxx.x.x.x:8000/`
, sin embargo, estoy necesitando que al ejecutar me dirija a la página de login: `http://xxx.x.x.x:8000/login`, ya que esta será mi página principal.
`Mi urls.py` del proyecto es el siguiente:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
]
```

El `urls.py` de mi app es:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views

app_name = "main"
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.login,name="login")
]
```

Y mi `views.py` es:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def login(request):
    return render(request,'registration/login.html')
```

Estuve buscando la forma de conseguirlo, pero por el momento no logro el resultado esperado, ¿cómo podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

yo tengo lo mismo y me funciona, lo unico que tengo distinto es que el nombre de la view es login_request, te paso como yo lo tengo y funciona.

```
    path("", views.login_request, name="login"),
path("logout/", views.logout_request, name="logout"),
```

en view:

```
def login_request(request):
```